# Put array inside an array while in loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Im working on a simple app that scans an array of websites, what I'm trying to do is save the urls in an array then put that in another array, my problem is only the result of the first domain on the array is being displayed(sorry my observation is wrong earlier).

```
    <?php

        $arrDomains = array('http://example1.com/', 'http://example2.com/');

        $arrExternals = array();
        for($i = 0; $i < count($arrDomains); $i++){

            $domain = test_input($arrDomains[$i]);

            $domain = filter_var($domain, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

            // START HERE

            $html = file_get_contents($domain);

            $dom = new DOMDocument();
            @$dom->loadHTML($html);

            // grab all the on the page
            $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
            $hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");

            $external = array();

            for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
                $href = $hrefs->item($i);
                $url = $href->getAttribute('href');

                if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) !== false) {

                    if (strpos($url, 'mailto') === false) { // exclude emails

                        if (!in_array($url, $external)) {
                            array_push($external, $url);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            array_push($arrExternals, $external);

        }


?>
```

Comment: Which array is being overwritten? $arrExternals? $external? Can you post the output of a var_dump and post what you are expecting based on the URL's you are fetching?

Comment: is this correct? `$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");` or this -> `$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body/a");`

Comment: @McBern I found it here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/find-all-links-on-a-page/

Comment: @TimWickstrom.com sorry my observation is wrong

Comment: What is the result of var_dump for $arrExternals?

Comment: @McBern just this `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => http://www.convolutermachine.com/ [1] => http://www.itbotics.com/ [2] => http://www.cjrtec.com/ [3] => http://www.digitalcuttingsystems.com/ [4] => http://www.hotmeltcoatingmachines.com/ [5] => http://www.industrialknive.com/ [6] => https://www.facebook.com/Convoluter-Machine-1845553252325955/ [7] => https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCyWG7IhlwQ8B82kThhhI-hQ ) )` but I test 2 domains, only the first one being displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to change variable $i because it overrides $i in the first for loop. I changed one $i to $j:**

```
    $arrDomains = array('http://example1.com/', 'http://example2.com/');

    $arrExternals = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($arrDomains); $i++){

        $domain = test_input($arrDomains[$i]);

        $domain = filter_var($domain, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

        // START HERE

        $html = file_get_contents($domain);

        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        @$dom->loadHTML($html);

        // grab all the on the page
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
        $hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");

        $external = array();

        for ($j = 0; $j < $hrefs->length; $j++) {
            $href = $hrefs->item($j);
            $url = $href->getAttribute('href');

            if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) !== false) {

                if (strpos($url, 'mailto') === false) { // exclude emails

                    if (!in_array($url, $external)) {
                        array_push($external, $url);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        array_push($arrExternals, $external);

    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm banging my head, just because of that.